# How to find the subproblem using dynamic programming here?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are gas stations along the way at distance a1, a2, . . . , an from place A to place B. Filling up at gas station ai takes mi minutes. Your car can hold enough gas to go 100 miles, and you start with a full tank of gas. If you decide to stop at a gas station, you have to fill your entire tank up. How can I solve this problem via dynamic programming that finds where to stop and spend the minimum amount of time at gas stations during the trip?

Comment: seriously dude, do your homework. try it yourself and if you have a question we will try to help.

Comment: This is a similar question : http://anandtechblog.blogspot.in/2011/01/amazon-question-dynamic-programming.html . Find your way around this